# Linked List in C: Accessing current->next is neither NULL or !NULL; problem with adding new nodes

Tags: c, linked-list

So I encounter this problem where when I add nodes to an empty head in a specific sequence it doesn't work.
If I insert 2,1,3,4 so the second number is smaller than the first number, then it works. But if I add 2,3,4,5, then it doesn't work. I get a Segmentation fault (core dumped).
Can somebody tell me whats wrong here?

This is my struct and adding-method:

```
struct list_node{
    int value;
    struct list_node* next;
};

typedef struct list_node node_t;

node_t* add_element_sorted(node_t* head, int v){
    node_t* current = head;
    node_t* new = NULL;
    new = (node_t *) malloc (sizeof(node_t));
    if (new == NULL) {
        printf("error");
        exit(1);
    }
    new->value = v;
    printf("%d\n", new->value);

    if (current != NULL){  //check if first node is empty
        while(current->value < v){
            current = current->next;
            printf("broke \n");
            if(current->next == NULL){ // check if current node is the last then its next shoud be null
                break;      
            }
        }
    }

    if (current == head) {
        new->next = head;
        return new;
    } else {
        new->next = current->next;
        current->next = new;
        return head;
    }
}
```

At this part it returns me current->next is neither NULL or !NULL. What is current->next now?

```
if(current->next == NULL){ // check if current node is the last then its next shoud be null
    break;
}
```

My main looks like this:

```
int main(){
    node_t* head = NULL;
    head = add_element_sorted(head, 2);
    head = add_element_sorted(head, 3);
    head = add_element_sorted(head, 4);
    head = add_element_sorted(head, 5); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are assigning a value to `current` with `current = current->next;` and then trying to dereference `current` two lines later with `if(current->next == NULL) {...` - but you don't check if the value you have assigned to `current` (i.e. the *previous* `current->next`) is `NULL`. If it is, you'll get ***undefined behaviour***.

Comment: Yeah, you need to check both whether current is NULL _and_ whether next is NULL. Check _every_ pointer before dereferencing unless you somehow know it can't possibly be NULL.